# Use same install disk on multiple PCs (ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: installation, ubuntu-14.04

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 disk. I have sucsesfully installed it on my computer, but now I've got couple more of old computers and I was wondering if I could use same installation disk on 7 more PC's.

Thank you for answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there's no reason you should not be able to install Ubuntu as many times as you please using the same disk so long as the disk is not damaged.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

> After many years Ubuntu still is and always will be free to use, **share**
>   and develop.

from [about Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu)

And, from their [Intellectual Property Policy](http://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/intellectual-property-policy)

> You can download, install and receive updates to Ubuntu for free.
>
> You  can modify Ubuntu for personal or internal commercial use.
>
> You can
>   **redistribute** Ubuntu, but only where there has been no modification to
>   it.